# Cambiar posición de string y color

Tags: javascript, html

*Mi codigo lo que hace es crear un simple array y cargar los valores por teclado es este:*

**Archivo main.js**

```
function ciclos() {

  var arrayU = new Array(3);
  var f;
  for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) { // ARRAY LENGTH = 3 = FOR = 0, 1 , 3
    var v = prompt('Ingresa los 3 valores a multiplicar:','');
    arrayU[f] = parseInt(v);
  }
  var total = 1;
  //var multiplicacion;
  //var number;
  for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) {
 total = arrayU[f] * total;
}
  var c = document.write(total);
}
```

**Archivo index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Learning</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Multiplicacion DE VALORES MEDIANTE CICLOS, ARRAYS Y ACUMULADOR"onClick="ciclos();"/>

<b>La multiplicación de los valores es: </b><script>AQUI LO QUIERO</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Mi problema es que nosé como hacerlo y que ya lo he intendo pero no me resulta , también tengo la duda de como cambiar el color de la var c = document.write(total) , no quiero incluir todo el código js en el html , solo quiero hacer esto.**

Comment: ¿No sabes cómo hacer qué? ¿Cambiar de posición? ¿Cambiar de color? ¿Multiplicar los valores del arreglo? ¿Qué es `c`? Necesitas dar la mayor cantidad de datos en tus preguntas para se pueda comprender sin estar preguntando el objeto de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que identificar el elemento que quieres modificar por ejemplo: `var x = document.getElementById("Resultado");` luego ya puedes modificarlo, cambiando su html interno: `x.innerHTML = total;` , o cambiandole el color: `x.style.color = "blue";`

```js
function ciclos() {

  var arrayU = new Array(3);
  var f;
  for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) { // ARRAY LENGTH = 3 = FOR = 0, 1 , 3
    var v = prompt('Ingresa los 3 valores a multiplicar:','');
    arrayU[f] = parseInt(v);
  }
  var total = 1;
  //var multiplicacion;
  //var number;
  for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) {
 total = arrayU[f] * total;
}
  var x = document.getElementById("Resultado");
  x.innerHTML = total
  x.style.color = "blue";

}
```

```html
<button onclick="ciclos()">Click me</button>
<p>Resultado: <div id='Resultado'></div></p>
```

Comment: yay! muchas gracias